# How does Byte Pair Encoding work?

Tags: nlp, encoding

I am using [this](https://github.com/rsennrich/subword-nmt) to do some Byte Pair Encoding (BPE). My corpus looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/shamoons/4bf9e78cd92624bcb120644fb995454a).

When I run the `learn_bpe`, I get a vocabulary that looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/shamoons/14bc594c19cbd7a5f2fae2e36549ff0c).

```
e r
r e
o n
o r
t i
) ;</w>
a c
n t
' ,</w>
er r
a l
r o
h e
m e
```

When I try to combine it again to see if it worked with `ubword-nmt apply-bpe -c data/jsvocab.txt < data/javascript.txt > tst.txt`, [the resulting file](https://gist.github.com/shamoons/11750709c2f29f0078bb419c13a5b3f3) has a lot of strange `@` characters.

```
const p@@ re@@ F@@ or@@ m@@ at@@ t@@ e@@ d@@ B@@ l@@ o@@ c@@ k@@ N@@ a@@ me@@ s = {
    '@@ ap@@ i@@ -@@ p@@ ro@@ j@@ ect@@ s@@ '@@ : '@@ A@@ P@@ I P@@ ro@@ j@@ ect@@ s@@ ',
    '@@ b@@ a@@ s@@ i@@ c@@ -@@ c@@ ss@@ '@@ : '@@ B@@ a@@ s@@ i@@ c C@@ S@@ S@@ ',
    '@@ b@@ a@@ s@@ i@@ c@@ -@@ h@@ t@@ m@@ l@@ -@@ and@@ -@@ h@@ t@@ m@@ l@@ 5@@ '@@ : '@@ B@@ a@@ s@@ i@@ c H@@ T@@ M@@ L an@@ d H@@ T@@ M@@ L@@ 5@@ ',
    '@@ c@@ ss@@ -@@ f@@ le@@ x@@ b@@ o@@ x@@ '@@ : '@@ C@@ S@@ S F@@ le@@ x@@ b@@ o@@ x@@ ',
    '@@ c@@ ss@@ -@@ g@@ r@@ i@@ d@@ '@@ : '@@ C@@ S@@ S G@@ r@@ i@@ d@@ ',
    de@@ v@@ o@@ p@@ s@@ : '@@ D@@ e@@ v@@ O@@ p@@ s@@ ',
    e@@ s@@ 6@@ : '@@ E@@ S@@ 6@@ ',
    '@@ in@@ f@@ or@@ m@@ ation@@ -@@ se@@ c@@ ur@@ i@@ t@@ y@@ -@@ w@@ i@@ th@@ -@@ he@@ l@@ me@@ t@@ j@@ s@@ '@@ : '@@ I@@ n@@ f@@ or@@ m@@ a@@ ti@@ o@@ n S@@ ec@@ ur@@ i@@ t@@ y w@@ i@@ t@@ h H@@ e@@ l@@ me@@ t@@ J@@ S@@ ',
    j@@ q@@ u@@ er@@ y@@ : '@@ j@@ Q@@ u@@ er@@ y@@ ',
    '@@ j@@ s@@ on@@ -@@ ap@@ i@@ s@@ -@@ and@@ -@@ a@@ j@@ a@@ x@@ '@@ : '@@ J@@ S@@ O@@ N A@@ P@@ I@@ s an@@ d A@@ j@@ a@@ x@@ ',
    '@@ m@@ on@@ g@@ o@@ d@@ b@@ -@@ and@@ -@@ m@@ on@@ g@@ o@@ o@@ se@@ '@@ : 'M@@ on@@ g@@ o@@ D@@ B an@@ d M@@ on@@ g@@ o@@ o@@ se@@ ',
    '@@ t@@ he@@ -@@ d@@ o@@ m'@@ : '@@ T@@ h@@ e D@@ O@@ M@@ ',
    '@@ ap@@ i@@ s@@ -@@ and@@ -@@ m@@ i@@ c@@ ro@@ serv@@ i@@ c@@ e@@ s@@ '@@ : '@@ A@@ P@@ I@@ s an@@ d M@@ i@@ c@@ ro@@ serv@@ i@@ c@@ e@@ s@@ ',
    '@@ ap@@ i@@ s@@ -@@ and@@ -@@ m@@ i@@ c@@ ro@@ serv@@ i@@ c@@ e@@ s@@ -@@ p@@ ro@@ j@@ ect@@ s@@ '@@ : '@@ A@@ P@@ I@@ s an@@ d M@@ i@@ c@@ ro@@ serv@@ i@@ c@@ e@@ s P@@ ro@@ j@@ ect@@ s@@ '
}@@ ;
```

And so on. I'm not sure what I'm missing, but it seems that it didn't fully reconstruct the text from the vocabulary?

Comment: How many merge operations did you specify in your invocation to `learn-bpe.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your BPE vocabulary is quite small given how the strings you want to segment look like. The biggest problem here is that BPE expects tokenized sentences with tokens separated by spaces. The BPE model is not aware of JS syntax and you feed it with JS code, so there is no wonder that it does not learn anything syntactically plausible.

You can interpret the BPE file a log of what subwords got merged and you can see that the longest string you get is something like:

```
m').valueOf
H:mm').valueOf
```

I would recommend some preprocessing, perhaps some JS lexer, so it respects the syntax and perhaps bigger vocabulary.

Comment: Ideally, shouldn't BPE handle all of the tokenization and syntax?

Comment: No, it is designed to work with tokenized text. It only gradually merges most frequent pairs of subword units starting from characters. In JS code, these are obviously pairs like `);` or `.(` that cross the token boundaries.